# How Swift implement operators ++ and --?

Tags: swift, swift2

It appears in Swift we can overload existing unary and binary operators. In fact, when I declare an variable as **Int**, I can view its postfix **++** declaration as follows:

```
postfix public func ++(inout x: Int) -> Int
```

But when I overload the postfix **++** for my own class, can I achieve the same effect as **++** for Int? (value changed after return value is used)

Or I just cannot do the same thing, and custom prefix operators have no difference from postfix operators ?

Comment: Why couldn't you ? Hint : there is a temp variable involved :)

Comment: @X.L.Ant Aha I see! Thanks a lot. This also means we should constrain the use in value types, right?

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you mean.

Comment: @X.L.Ant you suggest copy the object to a temp variable, modify the original variable, and then return the temp variable. In the case the type is of reference type, this may cause a side effect (because the returned object and the modified object is not the same, and this implementation is hidden from outside). So I think constrain the use to value-typed object is a good idea.

Comment: Oh, right, sorry, I missed your point. AFAIK, yes, this will work only for value types, unless you're ready to create another object (including the mentioned side effects). That really depends of what you intend to do in your ++ overloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's trivial with a struct (shamelessly borrowing [t4nhpt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2172546/t4nhpt)'s answer)

```
postfix func ++ (inout foo: Foo) -> Foo {
    let tmp = foo
    foo.bar++
    return tmp
}

struct Foo {
    var bar = 0
}
```

It's harder with classes because they are reference types. You have to create a copy that starts out incremented. The following works but may be difficult to extend to more complex classes

```
postfix func ++ (inout foo: Foo) -> Foo {
    let tmp = foo
    foo = Foo(bar: tmp.bar + 1)
    return tmp
}

class Foo {
    var bar = 0

    init(bar: Int)
    {
        self.bar = bar
    }
}

var baz1 = Foo(bar: 1)
let baz2 = baz1++
print("\(baz1.bar), \(baz2.bar)") // Prints 2, 1
baz1++
print("\(baz1.bar), \(baz2.bar)") // Prints 3, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
prefix func ++ (inout foo: Foo) -> Foo {

    foo.bar++
    return foo
}

class Foo {
    var bar = 0
}
```

Using:

```
    var foo = Foo()
    ++foo

    print(foo.bar)
```

Comment: I think X.L.Ant's suggestion is what I want. But thanks anyway :)